# Split an array from URL parameter by comma and space delimiter in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, preg-split

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called Formidable Forms, but that shouldn't be a hindrance to this question.

There's a PHP Hook (https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/frm_setup_new_fields_vars/#kb-dynamically-populate-checkbox-field) which allows you to fill in checkbox fields dynamically, taking URL parameters and adding them to the checkbox fields as values. Great. But if you have more than one entry per parameter, as I do, it adds the whole array/string (I get mixed up) as one check box value.

For example, my URL Parameter is `&srch_main=one, two, three`. This adds a checkbox field with the value "one, two, three."

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically create three fields from that (array,) so field one would be 'one' field two would be two and so on.

I've edited the code slightly from the above link:

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
  if($field->id == 390){//Replace 125 with the ID of your field
    $values['options'] = array($_GET['srch_main'], $_GET['srch_own']); //Replace Option1 and Option2 with the options you want in the field
  }
  return $values;
}
```

What I'd like to do is something like `$_GET['srch_main'][0]`,  `$_GET['srch_main'][1]` to print the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.. entries of the parameter to fill in each as a separate value in the checkbox field. That edit for me gives be the 1st letter and the second later as separate field inputs, but not the word or phrase separated by the comma and space.

Thanks for the suggestion from @EL_vanja below to use explode. This makes sense to use but my implementation breaks the form:

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
  if($field->id == 390){//Replace 125 with the ID of your field
    $values['options'] = array($_GET['srch_main'], $_GET['srch_own']); //Replace Option1 and Option2 with the options you want in the field
  }
// $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
//echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
//echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
$exercises = explode(", ", $values);
  echo $exercises[0];
  echo $exercises[1];
  echo $exercises[2];
  echo $exercises[3];
}
```

**Resolved**
Issue resolved with help fro El_Vanja by exploding the string. Many thanks.

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 20, 2);
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){
  if($field->id == 390){//Replace 125 with the ID of your field
    $values['options'] = explode(', ',$_GET['srch_main']); //Replace Option1 and Option2 with the options you want in the field
  }
  return $values;


}
```

Comment: You're looking for [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode). Using comma as the delimiter, you can get your query string value as an array of values.

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja - Do you know how I could implement it with my code? I keep breaking the form. I've edited the question to include my attempt at your suggestion

Comment: What the original function did was adding to an array of options: `$values['options'] = array($_GET['srch_main'], $_GET['srch_own'])`. Seems like you would need to do the same thing, but within a loop over your exploded values.

Comment: Ahh after several attempts I think this is a bit beyond my hacky skills of putting this together. Thanks for your suggestions @El_Vanja. Perhaps I'll try another day

Comment: Seems I've misunderstood how the function works. Try to do the following: `$values['options'] = explode(',' $_GET['search_main'])` and see if it yields the desired results. Also, I'd suggest you avoid adding spaces inside your query string (`&srch_main=one,two,three` instead of `&srch_main=one, two, three`).

Comment: Ahh I got excited then but an error comes into play as soon as you add ` ',' `
And thanks for the tip about leaving the space out of the delimiter

Comment: @El_Vanja "syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')'"

Comment: It's my keyboard, sorry (it's slowly dying, some keys tend to be unresponsive). A comma is missing between the `explode` parameters. So it should be `explode(',', $_GET['search_main'])`.

Comment: @El_Vanja That's brilliant, thank you. There are actually two different parameters within this function: 
` $values['options'] = explode(', ',$_GET['srch_main'], $_GET['srch_own']); `
Do you know why explode wouldn't be working on both? Or would it automatically be limiting to 2 maybe?

Comment: `explode` only takes one string as a parameter (when you're in doubt, always carefully read the function documentation). Do you want multiple entries for `$_GET['srch_own']` also?

Comment: @El_Vanja I see. If possible, yes. but now I know that, I could always include another parameter which includes the other parameters in the URL. It'd be a bit a bit of a longer URL but shouldn't be a problem. I use 'srch_main' and 'srch_own' for another purpose but adding a parameter something like 'srch_main_own' in the function and exploding that would work just as well.
You've been really helpful and given me lots of your time today so thank you very much.